# Reporting toxic facebook groupchats

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-groups

I got put in a group chat full of leaking of strangers nudes and full of bullying, from bigoted insults in the guise of "dark humor" to encouraging suicide ("kys"). I want this group chat taken down and for all parties to not even see it in their inbox anymore.

If I report the groupchat, is there any risk of anyone knowing I reported it? Will people still see it but not be able to reply to it, or will it actually go away? And will Facebook tell them what particular messages caused them to take it down if it goes that far? Or is there another alternative to getting this groupchat taken down or deleted to other members?

Please help.